# How can I implement my square(), modulusSqaured() and add() methods in my Complex class?

Tags: java, methods, complex-numbers

I have a class called `Complex` which has accessor methods for the real and imaginary numbers as well as a method to represent the complex number as a string and a method to get the magnitude of the complex number. I am having trouble implementing my last three methods `square()`, which squares the complex number, `modulusSquared()`, which returns the square of modulus of complex number and lastly `add(Complex d)`, which will add the complex number d to this complex number. I have attempted this but I think I am understanding this wrong. Here is my code:

```
public class Complex { //real + imaginary*i

    private double re;
    private double im;

    public Complex(double real, double imaginary) {
        this.re = real;
        this.im = imaginary;
    }

    public String toString() { //display complex number as string
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer().append(re);
        if (im>0)
          sb.append('+');
        return sb.append(im).append('i').toString();
      }

    public double magnitude() {   //return magnitude of complex number
        return Math.sqrt(re*re + im*im);
      }

    public void setReal(double m) {
        this.re = m;
    }

    public double getReal() {
        return re;
    }

    public void setImaginary(double n) {
        this.im = n;
    }

    public double getImaginary() {
        return im;
    }

    public void square() {    //squares complex number
        Complex = (re + im)*(re + im);
    }

    public void modulusSquared() {   //returns square of modulus of complex number
        Math.abs(Complex);
    }

    public void add(Complex d) {    //adds complex number d to this number

        return add(this, d);

    }

}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This class should be immutable, if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `add` and `square` methods are pretty straightforward. From what I understand `modulusSquared` is *|x+iy| = Square Root(x^2 + y^2)*, so the implementation is also really simple for that, too:

```
public void add(Complex d) {    // adds complex number d to this number
    this.re += d.getReal();     // add real part
    this.im += d.getImaginary();// add imaginary part
}
public void square(){
    double temp1 = this.re * this.re; // real * real
    double temp2 = this.re * this.im; // real * imaginary (will be the only one to carry around an 'i' wth it
    double temp3 = -1 * this.im * this.im; // squared imaginary so multiply by -1 (i squared)
    this.re = temp1 + temp3; // do the math for real
    this.im = temp2;         // do the math for imaginary
}

public double modulusSquared() { // gets the modulus squared
    return Math.sqrt(this.re * this.re + this.im * this.im); 
}
```

Comment: My modulusSquared method will take the modulus of my complex number and then square this value. Thanks for your helo

Comment: @JohnSmith, tell me if this is what you wanted because my math knowledge is sub par! :P